# Excel VBA Run-time error '1004': Applicated defined or object-defined error - Need code assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

This is the code that I am having an error on in Excel:

```
Sub Start_EndDelayInMonth()
With Sheets("Analysis Worksheet")
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'This is where the error occurs.
If Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, 2).Value = 1 And Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, 3).Value = 1 Then

   Call CopyCells

End If

If Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("B" & i).Value = 1 And Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("C" & i).Value = 2 Then

   Call CopyCells

End If

If Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("B" & i).Value = 1 And Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range("C" & i).Value = 3 Then

    Call CopyCells

End If

'--Then the code continues on in the same fashion, ending with:
End With
End Sub
```

Can someone please help me understand why I am getting the run-time error?  Thank you!

---

The CopyCells code is:

```
Sub CopyCells()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
j = 26
k = 2
For i = 5 To LastRow

Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, j).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - k)).Value
Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - k)).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 1))).Value
Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 1))).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 2))).Value
Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 2))).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 3))).Value
Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 3))).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 4))).Value
Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 4))).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 5))).Value
Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 5))).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 6))).Value
Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 6))).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 7))).Value
Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 7))).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 8))).Value
Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 8))).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 9))).Value
Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 9))).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 10))).Value
Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 10))).Value = Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 11))).Value
Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 11))).Value = 0
j = j + 1
k = k + 1
Next i
If k < (k + 1) Then
Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, (j - (k + 10))).Value = 0
End If
End Sub
```

---

Comment: *On which line of code does the error occur ??*

Comment: Do you have any cells that evaluate to #N/A? I seem to recall getting that in my MP3 spreadsheet every now and then.

Comment: Maybe you are getting the error because the variable  **i** is unknown at this moment. You'll have to initialize it I guess. I'm no expert though :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses!  I guess I should have made it more clear where the error was (I drew an arrow to it in my code) - it's the line: `If Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, 2).Value = 1 And Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, 3).Value = 1 Then` <<<-- this is where I'm getting the error

@benjaminS, I did define "i" earlier in my code, at the top.   I did end up fixing my error.  Thank you for the comments though!  :)

Comment: Good to hear - consider [**answering your own question**](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is

```
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'This is where the error occurs.
If Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, 2).Value = 1 And Sheets("Analysis Worksheet").Cells(i, 3).Value = 1 Then
```

You can see that while you have defined `i` - it isn't assigned any value.